# How to get value from this json object

Tags: json

Here the json data. `[1,"GarageC","NUR841",1611241200]`
how do i get the GarageC out from json.decode?

Answer (score 0):

This is array you can retrieve value from array by index basis like array_name[index]

Comment: example local a = [1,"GarageC","NUR841",1611241200] json.decode(a)[1] ??